# How to replace a word with a php string with str_replace or preg_replace

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

How to replace a word with a php string with `str_replace` or `preg_match`?
my code is :

```
$html = crawl_website($self_url."linkboxmain.php");
$getout = "usrid:<?=$_GET['tag'] ?>";
$string = str_replace("usrid:",$getout,$html);
file_put_contents($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/linkboxshow.php', $string);
```

above code not work!!

I want to replace `"usrid:"` with `"usrid:<?=$_GET['tag'] ?>"` and then put it to linkboxshow.php file.

`crawl_website()` is a function to get html of a page.

Comment: What does `crawl_website` do? This `<?=$_GET['tag'] ?>` probably isn't present in the `$html`.

Comment: it gets html of web site

Comment: So the PHP is already run, the `<?=` has already executed and the value of the `GET` request is in its place. You could use a regex and search for `usrid:stuff` but you'll need to know what ends the `$_GET`'s value.

Comment: I don't want to put my $_GET['tag'] , i want to replace exact "usrid:<?=$_GET['tag'] ?>";

Comment: This `<?=$_GET['tag'] ?>` doesn't exist when you are crawling. If you know the URL you can easily extract that.

Comment: that's why i'm replacing "usrid:" with "usrid:<?=$_GET['tag'] ?>" . it's very simple question. how to replace "usrid:" with "usrid:<?=$_GET['tag'] ?>".

Comment: Oh then try, `= 'usrid:<?=$_GET[\'tag\'] ?>';`

Comment: wow it's working.  what was my problem?

Comment: oh, variable in "  " executes but not in '  ' . :-|

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `$_GET` gets evaluated as a variable, escape or enclose it in single quotes and should be good to go...

```
'usrid:<?=$_GET[\'tag\'] ?>';
```

Also might be worth checking out http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.double. because there are a few ways to go..

Answer (score 1):

Try it like this:

```
$html = crawl_website($self_url."linkboxshow.php");
$getout = "usrid:".isset($_GET['tag']) ? $_GET['tag'] : ''."";
$string = str_replace("usrid:",$getout,$html);
```

Comment: not work, I want to put exact code "usrid:<?=$_GET['tag'] ?>" in string.